# AppSync GraphQL query with nested objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm starting a new project using AWS Amplify, and have some trouble to correctly define my schema for my use case with nested objects

I have the following schema

```
type Company
  @model
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  teams: [Team] @connection (name: "CompanyTeams", sortField: "name")
}

type Team
  @model
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  users: [User] @connection (name: "TeamUsers", sortField: "createdAt")
  company: Building @connection (name: "CompanyTeams", sortField: "name")
  teamCompanyId: ID!
}

type User
  @model
{
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String
  name: String!
  email: String!
  team: Unit @connection (name: "TeamUsers")
}
```

I would like to be able to query a list of teams based on a list of companies and a user name.

For example, get all teams in companies A/B/C with user name starts with "David".

Is my current schema fine for that?

I can easily retrieve a list of teams based on the company with this kind of query

```
query listTeams {
  listTeams(filter: {
    teamCompanyId: {
      eq:"A"
    } 
  }) {
    items {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But not sure how to include search on the user model. Should I override the filter and add a new custom resolver including the new filters?

Also is using filters the best solution? I believe with DynamoDB filter is only applied after we got results from the query or scan. And due to the limitation of 1mb, it might introduce a lot of reads to retrieve some results?

Happy to get any insights as I'm relatively new with AppSync / GraphQL and DynamoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of the teams from company A/B/C that have a user whose username starts with 'David'?

For example the query below in SQL:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM companies c
JOIN teams t on c.id = t.company_id
JOIN users u on t.id = u.team_id
WHERE c.id in ('a','b','c')
AND u.username like 'David%';
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your reply.
Yes, that would work using SQL, but I would like to query it using GraphQL query

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Still not solved? Is it even possible to filter on nested models that are located in different tables?